# Eliminate render-blocking JavaScript and CSS in above-the-fold content - Wordpress

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, wordpress

I'm getting this error when checking my website with Google PageSpeed

> Eliminate render-blocking JavaScript and CSS in above-the-fold content.

I actually get an orange code for the desktop, but for the mobile I get a red code, and this is what bothers me most. I'm already using W3 Total Cache plugin (the free version of it), but no luck with sorting out this problem.

I've already tried a number of other plugins, but there's no difference. I don't know if it's because of the W3 plugin that might interfere with the other ones...

Comment: markup error message

Answer (score 0):

Assuming for a minute that you are using W3 with minification option turned on and configured correctly the issue is that many WP plugins, themes and what have you use the version option when registering their scripts.

This places a query string on the end of the javascript `src='http://example.com/some-javascript.js?ver=1.1'`. W3 Total cache doesn't minify these files.  You need to remove the `?ver=***`

Try this code: (found [here](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/get-rid-of-ver-on-the-end-of-cssjs-files))

```
function remove_cssjs_ver( $src ) {
    if( strpos( $src, '?ver=' ) )
        $src = remove_query_arg( 'ver', $src );
    return $src;
}
add_filter( 'style_loader_src', 'remove_cssjs_ver', 10, 2 );
add_filter( 'script_loader_src', 'remove_cssjs_ver', 10, 2 );
```

Oh, and to be clear you need to add that to the functions.php file.

Comment: I don't think it has to do with the '?ver='. I've previously sorted out this problem. The files it is complaining are 2 fonts.googleapis.com and some js files that go along the lines wp-content/cache/minify/blablablacode.js

Comment: I'm pretty sure that it will always complain about the Google fonts files.

The issue with the other is that while minifying the files W3 concatenates the filenames and hashes them as the final output. If the concatenated list is too long it splits to a second (and more) file. Thus giving two (or more) minified files.  There is a setting that you can adjust, i just forget what it is called.

Comment: I had another look at the plugin but still can't find the setting you are talking about. It would be of much help if you could at least point me in the right direction. Many thanks!

Comment: Thanks! I did that, but at any value above 190 the website gives an error. Plus, even if I change the value from 150 to 190 and leave the 'Disable minify automatic file name length test' enabled I can't see a difference in Google Speedtest.

Comment: Well, to be fair google speed test isn't the authority I'd choose. I've had similar difficulty adjusting to their standards. The best advice overall I could give is to take a hard look at the plugins you are using and decide which are truly necessary, eliminate those that aren't, delete those you are not using (yes, it makes some difference) and get down to just the basics. better still if you know coding, I'd even recommend combining the files manually and serving that.